# Ошибка: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: массивы, numpy

Всем привет!
Выходит следующая ошибка:

> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
> ```

Задал массив с координатами:

```
xc = np.array([630, 439, 1927, 1026, 955, 1339, 1410])  # coord. "x"
yc = np.array([1117, 1099, 1648, 1308, 1344, 1439, 1478])  # coord. "y"
```

Пытаюсь их впихнуть в формулу с условием:

```
if (x-xc)**2+(y-yc)**2 <= r*r:
```

где xc и yc наши массивы.

Суть ошибки пониманию, но не понимаю как сделать так, что бы массив туда смог интегрироваться :/
Заранее спасибо за ответы

Вот обсуждаемая часть кода, на всякий случай:

- star cicle

```
for i in range(0, 7):
    xc = np.array([630, 439, 1927, 1026, 955, 1339, 1410])  # coord. "x"
    yc = np.array([1117, 1099, 1648, 1308, 1344, 1439, 1478])  # coord. "y"
    r = np.array([5.57, 5.57, 5.57, 5.57, 5.57, 5.57, 5.57])  # set aperture rad. > 2*fwhm ("Set aperture radius")
    r1 = np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])  # set interior rad. ("Set gap width")
    r2 = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])  # set external rad. ("Set annulus thickness")
```

- coord. cicle

```
for x in range(150, 2000):
    for y in range(150, 2000):
        if (x-xc)**2+(y-yc)**2 <= r*r:
            A[i] += flux[x][y]
            d1 = d1+1
        if r1*r1 <= (x-xc)**2+(y-yc)**2 <= r2*r2:
            B[i] += flux[x][y]
            d2 = d2+1
B[i] = (B[i]/d2)*d1
C[i] = A[i] - B[i]  #уберает ФОН
mag[i] = 2.5*np.log10(C[0]/C[i])+m2
print("mag=", mag[i])
d1 = d2 = 0
```

Comment: И как должен работать “if” если для 60% значений условие выполняется , а для оставшихся нет?

Comment: @MaxU "if" полностью работает, т.к значение "xc"-центральная координата по х, а просто "x" - это уже новая координата по которой прога должна (по идее) проанализировать кадр(астрономический снимок), то бишь это "range(150, 2000)". 

Когда я ввожу координаты "xc" и "yc" и значения "r, r1, r2" вручную то код работает, я хочу сразу ввести все значения и координаты в массивы что бы не вводит все вручную, а просто указать в формуле сам массив.

Следовало уточнить этот момент, пардон.

Comment: Вы меня не совсем поняли - данная ошибка возникает если сравнивать вектор со скаляром. В результате сравнения получается вектор булевых значений True / False. Это приводит Numpy в замешательство. Как например должна выполняться следующая проверка: if [True, False, True]: ... ???

Comment: @MaxU так, я понял свою ошибку. Мне надо тут работать не с массивами а со списками, поэтому Numpy думает что я сейчас векторы ввожу в формулу и сравниваю. Спасибо!